# Why not implement the sp_std::fmt::Debug for AccountId32 in non-std

Tags: frame, no-std, accountid

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/d443f148ce0aa6a51798b86c6b3ae54113786f94/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L584-L595

Why not implement the sp_std::fmt::Debug for AccountId32 in non-std like in std?

Answer (score 2):

This was done to reduce the size of the wasm runtime.

However, it could probably be revisited on what are the gains of not having them in wasm.